# Does std::vector<T>::clear() call destructor of the content?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a std::vector of something (say,does std::vector::clear() call destructor of the content? For example, if I have a data as vector, is the following code valid?

```
char * pd;
for(vector<char *>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
  pd = *it;
  delete pd;
}
```

Or, is it redundant as data.clear() would do that? I presume not, i.e. manual deallocation of the content is needed. I presume, data.clear() will not call implicit destructor for the contents? Is it correct? This is for pre C++11.

Comment: `char *` has no destructor, but `vector::clear` does call the destructor when the type has it.

Comment: Yes manual deallocation is necessary unless you store smart_ptr(unique_ptr) in the vector.

Comment: Formally, your loop has undefined behavior.  (Practically, I wouldn't worry about it if you're going to call `clear` or destruct the vector immediately afterwards.  I wouldn't leave pointers to deleted objects in a vector otherwise, however.)

Answer (score 29):

To answer your title: [`std::vector<T>::clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) does call the destructor for each element. However, for primitive datatypes like `char*` the destructor is trivial (standardese for "does nothing") which is practically the same as if no destructor is called.

Note: A destructor is not the same as the `delete` operator.

So what your question should be: **"Does `std::vector<T*>::clear()` call `delete` on its elements?"** and here the answer is: No, it does not call `delete`. You have to do it manually like shown in your example code, or you can (and probably should) use objects like `std::string` or smart pointers instead of raw pointers. Those do the memory management for you, and their destructors (which get called, see above) call the `delete` for you.

Comment: `std::vector<T>::clear()` always calls the destructor of each element, but the destructor of a pointer is a no-op (or a pointer has a trivial destructor).  (Which comes out to about what you said in practice, but is closer to how the standard describes things.)

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for correcting that, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: informally you could say that destroying the vector destroys all the pointers too, but only the pointers, not the objects they point to ;)

Comment: IIRC, as an optimization, POD types don't have their destructors called.

Comment: @Adrian that's conceptually the same as POD destructors being no-ops.

Answer (score 9):

If your items are dynamically allocated and your vector contains pointers to them, you will have to  manually call `delete` on each pointer in that container before calling `clear()`. Otherwise you have a memory leak.

If they are objects that are not dynamically allocated then you do not need to do anything - the destructor (if there is one) of the objects in the vector will be called when the vector is cleared.

Answer (score 5):

std::vector clear() does call the destructor of each element in the vector:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

But in your case it won't delete the contents of your dinamically allocated memory. I suggest using *string* instead of *char**

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi: it does call the destructor for pointers. It's just that the destructor of a pointer is a trivial destructor that does nothing. It does not caall `delete` in particular (after all, you could have a `std::vector<char*>` where the `char*` are allocated on the stack).